# Return intersection of 3 tables with joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables : news, users_regions_favorites and users_categories_favorites. Each news has a region and a category.

I want to return all news that are related the a user's favorites (by the regions or categories he likes). And never return a news twice, so no UNION.

[image]

Is there a way to do this with join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use `UNION`:

```
SELECT n.id 
FROM   news n 
       INNER JOIN users_categories_favorites c 
               ON c.id = n.catid
WHERE c.uid = 1 -- your user here
UNION 
SELECT n.id 
FROM   news n 
       INNER JOIN users_regions_favorites r 
               ON r.id = n.regid
WHERE r.uid = 1; -- your user here
```

`UNION` will deduplicate, only `UNION ALL` won't.

But you can also do this using only `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.id 
FROM   news n 
       LEFT JOIN users_categories_favorites c 
              ON c.id = n.catid 
       LEFT JOIN users_regions_favorites r 
              ON r.id = n.regid 
WHERE c.uid = 1 OR r.uid = 1; -- your user here
```

- See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2124/1) showing both results.

Comment: I was sure that union would duplicate, but you are right : it doesn't! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could make (schematically) :

```
select distinct 
news where exists users_regions_favorites
union
news where exists users_categories_favorites
```